# Office 365 shared calendars

Tags: office365

we want (A-USER) to add events into a shared (with us) calendar of another user (B-USER).

in the https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Calendars list there aren't the shared calendars

posting a json event at the url: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('B-USER@email.bla')/events it reply with an error

how can we add events into shared calendars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Office 365 REST APIs!  At present we only allow access to mail, calendar and contacts belonging to the authenticated user.  So, your scenario of making changes to a shared calendar is not supported at this time.  Access to resources belonging to other users e.g. shared calendar is on our roadmap to support but we don't yet have a timeframe to share with you.

In the meantime, you can use our [Exchange Web Services SOAP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204119(v=exchg.150).aspx) to implement your scenario.  If you are using .NET, then we recommend you use [EWS Managed API](https://github.com/officedev/ews-managed-api) to make the EWS calls and if you are using Java, we recommend you use [EWS Java API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) to do the same.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633661(v=exchg.80).aspx) for info on how to create appointments on a calendar using EWS Managed API or raw SOAP request/response.

Hope that helps ...

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: I have created a Native Android app using Office 365 REST API to get an authenticated user's Calendar Events. I also have Room accounts that automatically receive meeting requests. The authenticated user has full control over these Room accounts but I am not able to get Calendar events from these Room accounts using the authenticated user. Is this possible? Is there a work-around using a Native app?

Comment: Just posted a response to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594319/office365-api-admin-accessing-another-users-rooms-calendar-events/30596328#30596328

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT, Is this answer still application after a year?

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT could we get an update on this?

Comment: @jarcoal There is work going on to list calendars explicitly shared with a user foo@bar.com, as a calendar in the list https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars.  Once this work is complete, for calendars explicitly shared with a user, they would be able to add events, if they have sufficient permissions.  This should be available by end of the year.  Thanks.

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT That's great news, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Timeframe? Weeks? Months? Who-knows? Soon?

Comment: @Tinashe i just wanted to know how your get access to calendar room api,
I have created on app in ms account and not able to access apis. even though i have Private Key with app id, can you please help to get access to the apis.

Comment: @manish1706 You need an admin account, ie admin@domain.com
That account has rights to access calendar events.
With that I used https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api to get room events