# Accessing shared calendar using the O365 REST API

Tags: office365

I was reading question asked previously
[Office 365 shared calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266681/office-365-shared-calendars?rq=1)

Is the options to access shared calendars of authenticated user using Oauth to authenticate available now ?

Basically I am trying to implement a service using "OAuth2 client credential flow", but I want to access a calendar only if it is shared with a particular user using rest api call:
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users/"+emailId+"/calendargroups/"+"group id of Other Calendars"+"/calendars/{calendar_id of shared calendar}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This is now supported. There are new scopes to enable this. For example, if you used `Calendar.Read` before, you would use `Calendar.Read.Shared` to enable reading of shared calendars.

Comment: Is their any possiblity of adding this feature in future or I should use EWS apis only?

Comment: It might come in the future, but for now I don't have anything concrete to share.

Comment: This was 18 months ago. Any progress?

Comment: @JasonJohnston, I am not able to read/write a shared calendar from the API. I have set the required permission settings. The calendar is shared with `editor` permission. Any insight?